# How to upgrade an MSI install using Inno Setup installer?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

We recently moved from a Visual Studio setup msi-based installer to Inno Setup but we're having issues with upgrading existing installs using this new installer.  I know that the upgrade code remains static even as the product code changes every update, so I initially tried to set that as the AppId in the Inno Setup project, but that doesn't work.  I then tried a number of other guid's none of which work.

Is there a way to properly upgrade an msi install with an Inno Setup installer?

Answer (score 8):

No, I don't think so - InnoSetup is expressly **NOT** an MSI-based installer.

You will need to first properly uninstall your old MSI-based installation using e.g. msiexec /X (product-code or MSI file name), and then you can install the new stuff using InnoSetup.

Comment: Darn, was hoping for something easier.  Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

To install an .MSI file from within an Inno Setup installation, try these lines:

```
[Files]
Source: "Your-MSI-File.msi"; DestDir: "{tmp}"

[Run]
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\Your-MSI-File.msi"""
```

Credits for Alex Yackimoff
http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?msi

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this with an MSI package (replace with Inno Setup installer). I used the following code in the Inno Setup installer to automatically uninstall the MSI package (if installed) at installation time:

```
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): string;
var
  OldAppGuid, SubKeyName: string;
  OldAppFound: Boolean;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  NeedsRestart := false;
  result := '';
  if IsAdminInstallMode() then
  begin
    OldAppGuid := '{nnnnnnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnnnnnnnnnn}';
    SubKeyName := 'SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' + OldAppGuid;
    OldAppFound := RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SubKeyName);
    if not OldAppFound then
    begin
      SubKeyName := 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' + OldAppGuid;
      OldAppFound := RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SubKeyName);
    end;
    if OldAppFound then
    begin
      Exec(ExpandConstant('{sys}\msiexec.exe'),              // Filename
        '/X ' + OldAppGuid + ' /qb- REBOOT=ReallySuppress',  // Params
        '',                                                  // WorkingDir
        SW_SHOW,                                             // ShowCmd
        ewWaitUntilTerminated,                               // Wait
        ResultCode);                                         // ResultCode
    end;  
  end;
end;
```

Of course, replace `{nnnnnnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnnnnnnnnnn}` with the MSI package's product ID GUID.